# Closing HTML viewer from my app

Tags: android

I have a html file which I am opening by launching the HTML viewer. Is there a way to tell HTML viewer from my app to close the page?

Here is the code I am using to launch the html file

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
File file  = new File("/data/data/Sample.html");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/html"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i am sure you want to view this HTML file inside your application instead of launching native browser. If this is the case then create **WebViewClient** and set it inside the WebView.

For example:

```
private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and set it inside the webview as:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient ());
```

and then load that URL into the WebView actually. [**Here**](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/) is the detailed example.

Comment: Thanks Paresh...the above method gave me more control of the html file. thanks a lot, I am marking this as a correct answer !!!

Comment: @MayurPandey Glad that this is more helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to close the web page or transfer the control to other activity..If you go by the second option I would recommend you to use finish(); method at the close method where you use because it takes to the previous activity or you can choose your own destined activity.